# What do the colors mean on damage numbers?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have been using a Holy weapon for most of the game and so I assumed these yellow numbers indicated Holy damage.  Now I also have an Arcane weapon, but I never see a color for Arcane damage.  Do the colors mean something else?

[image: Cropped screenshot showing yellow and white damage numbers]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Yellow numbers are critical hits that you deal.
- White numbers are normal hits that you deal.
- Green numbers are healing you receive.
- Red numbers are damage you receive.
- Added in patch 2.4, orange numbers are the largest hit you dealt recently.

Blizzard's philosophy behind orange (and other) damage numbers is explained  thoroughly in [their blog post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19996041/engineering-diablo-iiis-damage-numbers-22-01-2016), but here are the rules regarding when they appear:

> - Damage numbers must be over 10,000 to be considered
> - If the damage number to be displayed is larger than the last that was displayed in orange, then display this new number in orange
> - Decay the value of the largest number by 3% every second
>
>   - This reduces the likelihood that you’ll go on too long without seeing any highlighted numbers
> - Ignore the first 10 large numbers
>
>   - This allows for the system to calibrate itself
> - If no damage has been dealt for 10 seconds, reset the system

Answer (score 3):

In addition to dpatchery's [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66874/80141), there is now (patch 2.4 also an orange mode, which is your most damage done in some time (see also [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/251742/80141) question).