# What do the damage colors mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

With patch 2.4, damage numbers are now compressed but I noticed that some are colored differently than others.  What do these colored numbers mean?  At first I thought any number in the billions are orange, but that's not the case.  I also don't think its critical hits because my crit chance is 60% but I still mostly see yellow numbers.

[image: Colored Numbers]

Comment: You can also turn off damage number compression in the UI options if you want to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The orange numbers are the maximum damage you did in a short while. You can hear it in this Youtube video (or read the quote below):

> While we're at it we also call out, you know, your highest damage points in orange and they kind of float and hang little bit longer so you can really see those calls out of how your damages doing.

Comment: There is also a new blog post explaining it all.
http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/19996041/engineering-diablo-iiis-damage-numbers-22-01-2016